# Подправить логику проверки 2fa Auth (от гугл) php

Tags: php, сессия, 2fa

Написал проверку 6-го кода при авторизации так как делал это впервой в голове есть замечания к некоторым нюансам:

**Добавилось два запроса к базе:**
1, в методе `loginProcess()` что бы проверить включена ли у пользователя 2fa auth или нет.
2, в методе `auth2stepProcess()` что бы узнать секретный ключ пользователя.

**Добавилась еще одна сессия:**
В методе `loginProcess()` где происходит проверка на наличие включенной 2fa auth, в сессию записываются данные с формы авторизации, что бы добросить их к другому методу, а именно `auth2stepProcess()`

Ниже представлю методы с контроллера юзера, почистив их от попутных (не влияющих на картину) проверок, что бы сосредоточиться на нужном коде.

Вопросы:
Как можно оптимизировать эти методы, например уменьшить кол-во запросов к бд, и избежать, например, записи данных в сессию и другие возможные полезные изменения.

```
    function login()
{

    if(user::i()->isLogged())
    {
        switch(APP_CODE)
        {
            case 'admin':
                location(APP_URL);
            break;

            default:
                location(APP_URL.'user/acount');
            break;
        }
    }

    $this->_template = 'users/login.tpl';
    $data = array();
    $secret = 'c6Pg4CWJ6LfFSJ4eb4Hc6Pg4CWJBUAAAAANdzzwSZJxaWBJ3';
    
    $this->assign('login_data', $data);
}

function loginProcess() // обработчик формы
{
    $data = $this->request; // получаем данные с формы


    $user = database::i()->user('login = ?', $data['login'])->fetch(); // запрос бд для того, что бы узнать включен ли у пользователя режим 2fa


    if ($user['google_protected'] != 'inactive') { // проверка на 2fa auth

        $_SESSION['data_login'] = $data;
        location(WS_FRONTEND.'/login/auth2step'); // отправляет на форму вводу 6 значного кода, метод auth2stepForm()

    }


    if($user = user::i()->login($data['login'], $data['password'])) // если у пользователя не включен 2fa просто авторизируем его
    {
        if(user::i()->isAdmin())
            location(WS_FRONTEND.'/admin');
        else
            location(WS_FRONTEND.'/user/acount');
    }
    else
    {
        user::i()->setFlash('users_login_error', array(
            'data' => $data
        ));

        location(APP_URL.'login');
    }
}

function auth2stepForm() // шаблон формы для 6 значнного кода
{
    $this->_template = 'users/auth2_form.tpl';

}

function auth2stepProcess() // обработчик формы где пользователь вводит 6 значный код
{
    $user = database::i()->user('login = ?', $_SESSION['data_login']['login'])->fetch(); // запрос в базу, что бы узнать секретный ключ пользователя
    $googleCode = $this->request; // получение данных с форму (6 значный код)

    $authenticator = new GoogleAuthenticator();

    $secret = $user['google_secret']; // получаем секретный ключ пользователя

    $tolerance = 2;


    $checkResult = $authenticator->verifyCode($secret, $googleCode['google_secret'], $tolerance);

        if ($checkResult) // если истина происходит тот же процесс, что и в методе loginProcess()
        {
            // копия с метода обработчика формы логина

            if($user = user::i()->login($_SESSION['data_login']['login'], $_SESSION['data_login']['password']))
            {
                if(user::i()->isAdmin())
                    location(WS_FRONTEND.'/admin');
                else
                    location(WS_FRONTEND.'/user/acount');
            }
            else
            {
                user::i()->setFlash('users_login_error', array(
                    'data' => $data
                ));

                location(APP_URL.'login');
            }
        }

        else
        {

            location(APP_URL.'login');


        }
}
```

Comment: Заметил, что вы в сессии храните полную форму авторизационных данных, что не безопасно. Мне кажется, что на первом этапе надо делать проверку на логин и пароль, потом смотреть есть ли у пользователя 2fa авторизация. Если есть, записываем в сессию id пользователя и перекидываем на страницу ввода 6-го кода. На втором этапе достаем пользователя по id из базы делаем проверку и окончательно авторизовываем пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, с первой частью, более чем согласен, в сессию записывались данные введенные пользователем в форму, как раз для того, что бы на втором этапе с помощью их авторизовать пользователя, как можно обыграть этот момент? Не доставать же данные для авторизации с базы?

Comment: Авторизацию как раз и делать на втором этапе по ID пользователю, т.к. на первом этапе у вас произошла аутентификация. Не путать авторизацию и аутентификацию. На втором этапе вы точно знаете что пользователь ввел правильный логин и пароль и заново они вам не нужны. У вас будет только ID пользователя, по которому вы сможете проверить правильно ли он ввел шестизначный код. В любом случаи каждый запрос авторизованного пользователя делает запрос в БД для то го чтоб, к примеру, достать его имя ну и т.д.